# JestJS react native and styled-components: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Text')

Tags: react-native, jestjs, styled-components

Running a jest test on a very basic `App.tsx` file throws the following error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Text')

       9 | `;
      10 |
    > 11 | const DefaultText = styled.Text`
         |                            ^
      12 |   font-family: 'Inter';
      13 | `;
      14 |

      at Object.Text (src/ui/themes/Typography.ts:11:28)
      at Object.require (src/ui/themes/MainTheme.ts:2:1)
      at Object.require (mock/testmocks/styled-components.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.require (src/ui/styledComponents/Button.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.require (src/ui/styledComponents/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.require (src/ui/screens/WelcomeScreen.tsx:6:1)
      at Object.require (src/App.tsx:4:1)
```

I created a generic test ensure my Jest config was correct

```
test('sample test', () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

It ran with no errors. So I conclude that jest is setup correctly.
I have a very basic test file `App.test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import App from '@src/App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(<App />);
  });

  // Add more test cases as needed
});
```

UPDATE: The following is the entire App.tsx.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import WelcomeScreen from '@src/ui/screens/WelcomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from '@src/ui/screens/LoginScreen';
import MainTabNavigator from '@navigation/MainTabNavigator';
import {AuthProvider} from '@context/AuthContext';
import {navigationRef} from '@navigation/navigationUtils';
import {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components/native';
import {MainTheme} from '@themes/MainTheme';

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={MainTheme}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <RootStack.Navigator>
            <RootStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
            <RootStack.Screen
              name="MainTabNavigator"
              component={MainTabNavigator}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          </RootStack.Navigator>
        </AuthProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Nothing fancy. Just a straightforward entry point into the app.

Comment: Is your `App` component wrapped by `ThemeProvider` within `@src/App` file?

Comment: App contains the ThemeProvider, not the other way round. So `<App><ThemeProvider></ThemeProvider></App>`. App.tsx contains all the global providers.

Comment: Can you share the code for `App.tsx`?

Comment: Possible to share a github repo link having this issue?

Comment: @RobinThomas App.tsx added to original post